# What's the best way to determine if NamedDataSlot exists

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Actually I come up with the following implementation

```
bool DoesNamedDataSlotsExist(string name)
{
    try
    {
        Thread.AllocateNamedDataSlot(name);
    }
    catch
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The obvious problem here: If some code calls `DoesNamedDataSlotExist()` twice, it will first generate `false` then `true` (which could be optimized if i would use `Thread.FreeNamedDataSlot()` ...)

But is there any better way?

**EDIT**

source of `GetNamedDataSlot`

```
public LocalDataStoreSlot GetNamedDataSlot(string name)
{
    LocalDataStoreSlot slot2;
    bool tookLock = false;
    RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions();
    try
    {
        Monitor.ReliableEnter(this, ref tookLock);
        LocalDataStoreSlot slot = (LocalDataStoreSlot) this.m_KeyToSlotMap[name];
        if (slot == null)
        {
            return this.AllocateNamedDataSlot(name);
        }
        slot2 = slot;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (tookLock)
        {
            Monitor.Exit(this);
        }
    }
    return slot2;
}
```

Somehow I would need to access `this.m_KeyToSlotMap`...

Comment: Do you really need NamedDataSlots, the documentation says "For better performance, use fields that are marked with the ThreadStaticAttribute attribute instead."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can duplicate the behavior you observe in GetNamedDataSlot source.

You can introduce special entity, say Thread local storage adapter, that will maintain the dictionary of already allocated data slots. All allocations of data slots should be made via this entity.

Here's what I mean

```
internal static class TLSAdapter
{
    static Dictionary<string, LocalDataStoreSlot> tlsSlots = new Dictionary<string, LocalDataStoreSlot>();

    public static bool DoesNamedDataSlotsExist(string name)
    {
        lock(tlsSlots)
        {
            return tlsSlots.ContainsKey(name);
        }

    }

    public static LocalDataStoreSlot AllocateNamedDataSlot (string name)
    {
        lock(tlsSlots)
        {
            LocalDataStoreSlot slot = null;
            if ( tlsSlots.TryGetValue(name, out slot) )
                return slot;

            slot = Thread.GetNamedDataSlot(name);
            tlsSlots[name] = slot;
            return slot;            
        }       
    }   
}
```

Comment: that's really nice! ... but ... you forgot one thing: as you store the `LocalDataStoreSlot` inside a dictionary, there will never be a chance to get garbage collected ... you should add the `ThreadStatic`-Attribute to the private dictionary and you're done! using `ThreadStatic` also means, that you can do the whole allocation/checking without any lock!

Comment: If private dictionary is marked as ThreadStatic then every thread will have its own instance, so of one thread allocates a slot - other thread has no chance knowing about it (it will have its separate dictionary instance). To make those slots GC collectible you can add delete method to the TLSAdapter

Comment: ahh ... sry ... actually my requirements changed a little bit, and `If private dictionary is marked as ThreadStatic then every thread will have its own instance` is exactly what i wanted :) ... anyway ... yes!